# Issue on returning a variable from an evalScript function

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, cc-2019

I am working on a **CEP HTML panel** for **Photoshop** and I want to **check** first if there is any **opened documents** before my panel do what it has to do. So I made something like this into my **index.js** so to test if I get the correct result. But `psDocumentsLength` variable returns as undefined. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
(function()
{
   'use strict';

    var csInterface = new CSInterface();
    var psDocumentsLength; //1//

    function init()
    {
        themeManager.init();
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            check_PSDocumentsLength();
            alert(psDocumentsLength); //4//
        });
    };

    init();

    function check_PSDocumentsLength() //2//
    {
        var chosenFunction = 'checkDocumentsLength()';
        csInterface.evalScript(chosenFunction, function(result)
        {
            psDocumentsLength = result; //3//
        });
    };

}());
```

Comment: Probably an issue of code async. What if you put your alert() in the callback function, near //3//?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy if I put the `alert` into callback function it works, but my problem is that I can't pass the result out of the callback function to `psDocumentsLength` variable at //1//!!! :( The `alert` at //4// it's just for test the `psDocumentsLength` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, considering what **Sergey Kritskiy** said about issue of **code async**, I tried to add a `setTimeout` after `check_PSDocumentsLength()` function call and it worked!!! So my code now looks like this...

```
    (function()
    {
       'use strict';

        var csInterface = new CSInterface();
        var psDocumentsLength; //1//

        function init()
        {
            themeManager.init();
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                check_PSDocumentsLength();
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    alert(psDocumentsLength);
                }, 1000); //4//
            });
        };

        init();

        function check_PSDocumentsLength() //2//
        {
            var chosenFunction = 'checkDocumentsLength()';
            csInterface.evalScript(chosenFunction, function(result)
            {
                psDocumentsLength = result; //3//
            });
        };

    }());
```